# CS50 PSet4: Recover - Conditional Statement Problem

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, cs50

I have written the code for PSet-4: Recover from CS50 and I have a question regarding the usage of if-else statements in my code inside the while loop.
When I run the first code, check50 shows the following errors -

```
:) recover.c exists.
:) recover.c compiles.
:) handles lack of forensic image
:( recovers 000.jpg correctly
    expected exit code 0, not None
:( recovers middle images correctly
    expected exit code 0, not None
:( recovers 049.jpg correctly
    expected exit code 0, not None
:| program is free of memory errors
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

I tried writing this code and it fails.

```
    char jpeg[8]; //to store each jpeg file
    int i = 0; // to count the number of jpeg files
    BYTE buffer[512]; // store each stream of 512 bytes to read
    FILE *imout; // output file
    bool jpegStart = false; // to check for already opened jpeg file

// read the file 512 bytes at a time until the end
    while (fread(buffer, 1, 512, card) == 512)
    {
        // if buffer detects signature first 4 bytes of JPEG file
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && ((buffer[3] & 0xff) == 0xe0))
        {
            //if already jpeg opened and new detected, close the already opened jpeg
            if (jpegStart)
            {
                fclose(imout);
            }
            //set true when signature detected and write to output file with current index i
            else if (jpegStart == false)
            {
                jpegStart = true;
                sprintf(jpeg, "%03i.jpg", i);
                imout = fopen(jpeg, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, imout);
                i++;
            }
         }
     }
```

Whereas when I run the code without the else if clause, it runs successfully as per the following code:

```
    char jpeg[8]; //to store each jpeg file
    int i = 0; // to count the number of jpeg files
    BYTE buffer[512]; // store each stream of 512 bytes to read
    FILE *imout; // output file
    bool jpegStart = false; // to check for already opened jpeg file

// read the file 512 bytes at a time until the end
    while (fread(buffer, 1, 512, card) == 512)
    {
        // if buffer detects signature first 4 bytes of JPEG file
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && ((buffer[3] & 0xff) == 0xe0))
        {
            //if already jpeg opened and new detected, close the already opened jpeg
            if (jpegStart)
            {
                fclose(imout);
            }
            //set true when signature detected and write to output file with current index i
 
            jpegStart = true;
            sprintf(jpeg, "%03i.jpg", i);
            imout = fopen(jpeg, "w");
            fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, imout);
            i++;
        }
     }
```

I think it might be a very silly doubt but I would still like to get some clarification on why the first code failed when the else-if conditional statement was included? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, `jpegStart` is never reset to `false`. As a consequence, the condition:

```
if (jpegStart)
```

remains true and the `else if` is discarded.

The first example goes like:

```
if (jpeg is true) { 
    do this..
} else if (jpeg is false) {
    do this..  /* This line is only executed if jpeg is false */
}
```

The second example on the other hand translates to:

```
if (jpeg is true) {
    do this..
}

do this.. /* This line always executes */
}
```

Do you see the difference?

Here's an example that might help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void print_greatest(int x, int y) 
{ 
    if (X > y) {
        printf("%d\n", x);
    } 
    printf("%d\n", y);
}

int main(void) 
{
    print_greatest(10, 5);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Output:

```
10
5
```

`y` always gets printed. But if we were to add an `else`, things change:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void print_greatest(int x, int y) 
{ 
    if (x > y) {
        printf("%d", x);
    } else {
        printf("%d", y);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    print_greatest(10, 5);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Output:

```
10
```

`y` is only printed if it was greater than `x`.

**Side note:**

You should always check the return value of `fopen` to ensure you're not — trying to — reading from or writing to a `NULL` pointer. Functions like `fwrite` and `fclose` should also be checked.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I get it now. So when I use the `else if` clause, my code writes onto the file the first time (when `jpegStart = False`) but after that for next iterations, it never writes to the file at all. I hope my understanding is correct?

Comment: Exactly, because the ```else if(jpegStart == false)``` remains false and we never enter the block.